# Smooth flicker animation of an object in Spark AR

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

i'm looking for a way to make an object flicker smoothly. Not just over toggling the visibility.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you can animate the opacity of the object's material in script.